# Convert APDU to SmartCard from protocolo T=0 to T=1

Tags: c#, smartcard

I am developing an application for SmartCard and when I work with the T=0 protocol the application runs perfect, but for T=1 SCardTransmit function returns

> invalid parameters ERROR 80100004.

My question is the vector has the same format for both protocols or change the vector format?

```
public void Trasmision()
{
    **Byte[] vectorSend = { 0x00, 0xa4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6f, 0x65 };**
    UInt32 inT2 = (UInt32)vectorSend.Length; 
    vectorIn = new Byte[254];
    UInt32 inT = (UInt32)vectorIn.Length;
    IntPtr PT1 =GetPciT0() ;
    this.rTransmit = SCardTransmit(this.hContext, GetPciT1(), vectorSend, inT2, request, vectorIn, inT); 
}
```

Comment: You should translate your title to english :)

Comment: APDU to PC/SC  (SmartCard) protocol T1

Comment: Do you have `SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1` in your `SCardConnect` call? Did you try `Byte[] vectorSend = { 0x00, 0xa4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x6f, 0x65, 0x00 };` or `Byte[] vectorSend = { 0x00, 0xa4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x02, 0x6f, 0x65, 0x00 };` (which is strange)? Is the card a (U)SIM?

Comment: SCardConnect(this.hContext, MyReader , EXCLUSIVE ,T1|T0 , ref this.hContext, ref ActiveProtocol);

Comment: work with smart cards (jcop21 and j2c40)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While T=0 knows only a P3 which has to be analyzed depending on command case, T=1 differentiates between LC for length of command data and LE for length of response. Note that LE has to **follow** the command data field.

While I'm not aware of the C# API, I guess the problem originates from the 00 before 6F. This can't be LC (because I assume 6F 65 is the command data, therefore it should read 02) and as it stands, it will be interpreted as an extended length indication for an LC with 6F 65, but no command data following.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for the information
fijate now I have this that I read with an application from my smart cards, but I'm wrong are the respective commands to work, are so well or should modify them to tramajar with T1 protocol

Comment: SELECT ISD using zero length AID
00 a4 04 00 00
SELECT FILE Master File (if available)
00 a4 00 00 00
SELECT FILE Master File by identifier (if available)
00 a4 00 00 02 3f 00 00